# My JSON fetch method fetch just once

Tags: json, swift

I have method which fetch data from JSON file. It works fine, when I run app first time, but when I update data in JSON file and look back to my app the data does not change. I have to delete app and upload it again. What's wrong with my code?

```
let requestURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://www.example.com/json.txt")!
        let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: requestURL as URL)
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest as URLRequest) {
            (data, response, error) -> Void in

            let httpResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse
            let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

            if (statusCode == 200) {
                print("Everything is fine, file downloaded successfully.")

                do{

                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.allowFragments) as! [String: AnyObject]
                    if let JSONSchools = json["skoly"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]{

                        for school in JSONSchools {

                            if let name = school["nazev"] as? String {

                                if let city = school["mesto"] as? String {

                                    if let id = school["id"] as? String {
                                        self.schools.append(School.init(name: name, city: city, id: id))
                                    }

                                }

                            }
                        }
                        self.fetchFinished = true
                    }

                } catch {
                    print("Error with Json: \(error)")
                }
            }
        }

        task.resume()
    }
```

Thanks for help

Comment: You will need to fire the method again in order to see the updated data. Your app wont automatically find the updates to the JSON file. If you are using a view controller, you could try putting calling this code from the `viewWillAppear()` method

Comment: How you call this function, on button click or any other event ?

Comment: I call it every time when user hits button.

Comment: Don't you need to refresh self.schools when the button is clicked? self.schools = [] before making a call?

Comment: This is not the problem. I do it every time before I call the method.

Comment: I debugged my code and it really fetch data but still the same, so for example if in json file are 7 objects at first and then some are added or removed it will still load the same 7 objects even if I restart it, but if I deleted and upload it. It works fine and then again doesn't. So I think it must save the data, but I don't know how.